# Definition of double integral for an specific case

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Well, this problem was in a test of mine and I couldn't do it. I tried to do using the definition based in supremum and infimum theory. I would like to could I solve this one in both ways, or the simplest one to understand. It is the following statement:

Show, using the definition of double integral, that the function

$$ f : (x, y) \in [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1] \mapsto
\begin{cases}
1; (x, y) \in \{(0, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)\} \\
0; (x, y) \not\in \{(0, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)\}
\end{cases}
$$

is integrable. Besides, evaluate the integral of $f$ in $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$.

Comment: well... $f$ is zero apart from a finite set of values, so the integral is zero..

Comment: Yes, it is. But I have to use the definition.

Comment: consider an easier question, let $f(x) = 1$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, can you show that $\int f dx = 0$? can you generalize it to your case?

Comment: Yes, it is quite obvious that it is zero. But the focus of the problems is not the result, is the application of the definition. In my test I tried to use step functions at the top and at the xy plane, but I couldn't finish. My professor used finite (or infinity(?)) sums to solve but I didn't undestand how to proceed step by step. My focus was proving that the sup integral of the low step function minus the inf integral od the above one was less than an epsilon.

Comment: ok, if you want the step function kind of proof, you first need to make sure you know how to solve the easier question in my previous comment.

Comment: the generalization to the 2-dimensional case is very easy, instead of "small intervals" around the bad points you take small rectangles

Comment: if you project to Y it becomes a dot, dot has content zero, so it is zero. Is that right?

Comment: ah yes you are right, but can you prove it with the sup-inf method? I'll write a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is easier than it seems. We have to remember that the integral is just  a sum and the double integral is just a double sum. Also, when defining the integral we observed that the length (similarly area) for the partitions are not fixed.

Hence, we get the same definition if $\Delta x = (b-a)/n$ and $\Delta y = (c-d)/m$ where $n,m$ denote the number of intervals in the partitions of the $x,y$-axis respectively. Hence it follows immediately that,

\begin{align*} \iint_{[-1,1]^2} f \ dA =  \lim_{n,m \to \infty} \sum_{i,j}^{m,n}f(p_{ij}) \ \Delta x \Delta y &= \lim_{n,m \to \infty} \sum_{\textrm{$i,j$ s.t $f \not = 0$}} f(p_{ij}) \Delta x \Delta y  \\ \\ & \leq \lim_{n,m \to \infty} \Delta x \Delta y = 0\end{align*}

Comment: Yes. It is also correct. Do you know how can I relate it to upper and lower integral? Because If I find that the upper and lower are equal, the integral it self is equal the upper and lower integral.

Comment: Yea, we could analyze the single using Fubini-Tonelli, but then the solution would be longer and require more analysis. At least this way you don't have to see much of it. I'm glad this worked, but yeah I always think of integrals as sums, you only get those nice properties with antiderivatives i.e fundamental theorems in special cases (at least in computation).

Answer (score 1):

First we will prove the following easier question

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(1)=0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Let me prove that $\int f dx =0$

for every partition $P=\{0,x_1,...,x_n=1\}$ of $[0,1]$ we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \min_{x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x) |x_i-x_{i-1}| = 0$$

It follows that the lower integral is always zero.

Now it is left to show that so is the upper integral, that is, we need to show that 
$$\inf_{P=\{x_1,...,x_n\}} \sum_{i=1}^n \max_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)|x_i-x_{i-1}|=0$$

by the definition of $f$ we have that $\max_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)=0$ so we only have to deal with the last interval.

Now I will give a sketch, first note that for every partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ you have that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \max_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)|x_i-x_{i-1}|$$ is non-negative, therefore it is enough to finte a sequence of partitions $P_n$ such that the corresponding sum convergence to $0$ (why?).

Here is how to construct these partitions:

set $P_n = \{0,1-1/n,1\}$ you have that the sum corresponds to $P_n$ is
$$\max_{x\in[0,1-1/n]} f(x) (1-1/n) + \max_{x\in[1-1/n,1]} f(x) (1/n)=0\cdot(1-1/n)+1\cdot 1/n=1/n\rightarrow 0$$

Thus we show that $f$ is integrable with integral zero.

How do we generalize this to the 2 dimensional case? so the Lower integral is again always zero (because the minimum on every rectangle is $0$) so again we only have to show that the upper integral is zero, how we do that? again you only have to find a partition (now a partition is a set of rectangles) such that the sums corresponding to the partitions convergence to zero. How we choose the partition? we take $P_n$ to be a set of rectangles with edge of lenth $1/n$ containing the "bad points" which in your case are $\{(0,0),(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1)\}$ and we don't care about the other rectangles because the maximum is anyway zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I understand know.

Comment: That's great, I was afraid you won't understand my English.